Comparison of predictive and planning model
I am choosing a topic to do research along these lines. Often the ideas of predictive and planning collide. They seem similar on the one hand and different on the other. I couldn't find anything obvious to distinguish. I want to know the difference between them; so, would you share your thoughts please?

Predictions are model-based, in many cases planning is business-based. So, finding a resource that combines them is one place to start. This book Strategy Beyond the Hockey Stick: People, Probabilities, and Big Moves to Beat the Odds is not a bad choice in that regard. https://getlucidity.com/strategy-resources/strategy-beyond-hockey-stick-summary/ This graphic summarizes it nicely. https://images.app.goo.gl/3vERLhB3Yf67HzhZ8
